# Creating Indoor Navigation System Using Wi-Fi Tracking

Tags: flutter, indoor-positioning-system

I want to create a small app using `flutter` that tracks my location inside my `100x100m` apartment. I am interested in creating an indoor navigation app for various places, but at the moment, I lack the knowledge on how to accomplish it, therefore setting the scope of the app to be very small and very local for testing purposes.

From what I could gather, there is three primary technology to use `BLE`(Bluetooth Low Energy),`Wi-Fi`and `UWB`(Ultra-wideband). I am planning to use`Wi-Fi` as it seems to be the most straight forward way, but I could be wrong on this matter.

The issue is that I don't know where to start learning about this or what kind of tools I would need to create the map for the house. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would be very happy and appreciative.

Comment: This is an extremely complex topic, and as such is off-topic for this site that focuses on concise solutions to specific and well-defined problems. You might try looking up research papers on the subject, though I will tell you right now that tracking your location with any degree of precision using simple local wireless technologies alone is going to be a monumental undertaking. I don't like to use the term "impossible", but for just one person who lacks the necessary experience to even know what to search for, it will be... challenging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you would use use beacons placed at known positions and use RSSI as analogue to distance and do something similar to GPS where you draw spheres around each beacon and where it all intersects is where your device is.

There's quite a few research papers if you search indoor localization using rssi measurements